# Yii project not working on server

Tags: yii

I have a project built in `yii` version 2.My issue is that the project is running as expected on localhost but not on the server.

I just copy pasted the folder from htdocs to server

> /var/www/html/project foler.

I did the necessary changes in the db. The first login page opens as expected but once I click on login, the next page doesn't open saying as `404 Page not found error`.

The login url is

> Server_IP/project/web

and then the redirecting url is

> Server/project/web/home

which is not found.

When checked further I noticed that the `yii` code isn't been detected for internal files other than the `Site` folder's `login.php` file.

Can someone please suggest what is the issue

Comment: 1. Please check your htaccess file. Does it exist? 2. Also try enabling the debug mode and send full error here so that help can be given. 3. Try `php init` on localhost and convert your app to production mode and then upload modified files. 4. Try these above steps and if you can send full error after enabling debug mode, it will be better to help properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the reply.
The problem was with .htaccess override.
I followed the below link and it worked as expected.

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/61009/how-to-enable-use-of-htaccess-in-apache-on-ubuntu

**First Step**

Open file as

```
sudo vim /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

**Second Step**

remove comment sign (#) if you find it before this line ( line number 187 approx.)

```
AccessFileName .htaccess
```

**Third Step**

Then find the line where there is

```
<Directory /var/www/>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverrideNone
     Require all granted
</Directory>
```

replace "None" with "All"
AllowOverride All

Restart apache once the changes are done with the following command

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

It will work well :)

Answer (score 0):

Check your `httpd.conf` and make sure Apache is set to respect .htaccess files local to the application.

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/429931) will point you in the right direction on how to achieve this